# Сортировка даты в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, сортировка, дата

Имеется БД в MS SQL Server, БД содержит жизненный цикл талона (тикета), который разработчик доводил до логического завершения.
Имею следующие столбцы, по которым нужно сортировать (как мне кажется):
ChangeDateMsk - столбец, который отображает время действия работы с талоном (обновил, закрыл, закомитил, перевел на кого-либо и т.д.),
PrTitle - столбец, который отображает название талона.
Что нужно: отсортировать значения по дате таким образом, чтобы все строчки из столбца ChangeDateMsk, которые относятся к определенному номеру талона из таблицы PrTitle были слиты в одну строчку, если диапазон разброса времени между ними составляет больше 5 минут, требуется исключить случайные действия разработчика, чтобы значения не дублировались. Приложил скрин, проще говоря, там есть талон 322274, хочу попытаться слить эти значения в одну строчку, как со стороны PrTirle, так и со стороны ChangeDateMsk.
Заранее спасибо, если вы поняли мои бредни(.

[image: Скриншот БД]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: *слиты в одну строчку, если диапазон разброса времени между ними составляет **больше** 5 минут* противоречит *талон 322274, хочу попытаться слить эти значения в одну строчку*, ибо там разброс 15 секунд, т.е. **меньше** 5 минут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот концептуальный пример.

Решение реализует две вещи:

- Отфильтровывает строки с интервалом менее 5 минут.
- Создает список ChangeDateMsk, разделенный запятыми.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PrTitle NVARCHAR(100), ChangeDateMsk DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl (PrTitle, ChangeDateMsk) VALUES
(N'#332274 Импорт', '2020-01-25T15:01:24'),
(N'#332274 Импорт', '2020-01-25T15:01:27'),
(N'#332274 Импорт', '2020-05-25T15:01:24'),
(N'#334244 Экспорт', '2020-10-25T05:01:24'),
(N'#334244 Экспорт', '2020-10-25T07:01:24');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(2) = ', ';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , IIF(LEAD(ChangeDateMsk) OVER (PARTITION BY PrTitle ORDER BY ChangeDateMsk) <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, ChangeDateMsk), 'true', 'false') AS [outcome]
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT PrTitle
    , STUFF((SELECT @separator + FORMAT(ChangeDateMsk, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS [text()]
         FROM rs AS O
         WHERE O.PrTitle = C.PrTitle
            AND o.outcome = 'false'
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(@separator), NULL) AS ChangeDateMskList
FROM rs AS c
WHERE c.outcome = 'false'
GROUP BY PrTitle;
```

**Результат**

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
|     PrTitle     |             ChangeDateMskList             |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| #332274 Импорт  |  2020-01-25 15:01:27, 2020-05-25 15:01:24 |
| #334244 Экспорт |  2020-10-25 05:01:24, 2020-10-25 07:01:24 |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает на вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить это как Ответ.